# How to set up pygame with Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, macos, pygame, pydev

Edit3: Additional information: I was able to get the Eclipse/pygame combo running on Windows... just not on MacOSX.

---

Edit2: Compiling from the shell also works. Just Eclipse now :)
What I've tried in Eclipse:

For the interpreter I use auto-config and it suggests `/usr/bin/python` as interpreter. Then for PYTHONPATH he suggests all the default stuff and I then add `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages` in addition to the rest. I still have the unresolved package "syntax" error in the code, but when compiling the only error he complains about is that there is no appropriate 64-bit architecture.

`../Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pygame/base.so: no appropriate 64-bit architecture (see "man python" for running in 32-bit mode)`

---

Edit: I've now managed to be able to `import pygame` within IDLE and initialise pygame. In Eclipse I added the pygame path to PYTHONPATH but Eclipse complains about the architecture.

---

I want to use pygame in combination with Eclipse, Pydev and Python 2.7.

First I downloaded Python 2.7.3 and installed it.
To be able to work in an IDE I installed Pydev on Eclipse. That all works and I am able to work in Eclipse with Pydev and the programs I test run without problems.

Then I went on and downloaded pygame and installed that too. ([pygame download](http://pygame.org/ftp/pygame-1.9.1release-python.org-32bit-py2.7-macosx10.3.dmg))

Now when I try:

```
import pygame
pygame.init()
```

Eclipse tells me: `unresolved import: pygame` and when I try to compile anyway I get following message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/name/Documents/workspace/test_unit/main.py", line 6, in <module>
import pygame
ImportError: No module named pygame
```

Also when I start the IDLE app and try there to import pygame I get following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
import pygame
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-    packages/pygame/__init__.py", line 95, in <module>
from pygame.base import *
ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-    packages/pygame/base.so, 2): no suitable image found.  Did find:
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pygame/base.so: no matching architecture in universal wrapper
```

However if I use `open Module...` via IDLE and then open pygame the module is found.
What am I missing?

Comment: execute python directly from the command prompt/bash shell...etc and try to import pygame.  What happens?

Comment: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 6, in <module>
    import pygame
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pygame/__init__.py", line 95, in <module>
    from pygame.base import *
ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pygame/base.so, 2): no suitable image found.  Did find:
 /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pygame/base.so: no matching architecture in universal wrapper`

Comment: This is what I get for `python main.py` where in main.py is only the following `import pygame` and then `pygame.init()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, I found the solution how to get it working. The key issues was that Eclipse chooses the 'wrong' interpreter. The Eclipse choice works fine for normal python stuff but when trying to compile pygame things it gets complicated and I get architecture errors.

So what I did:

1. Get Eclipse Classic 3.7.2 32-bit [here](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads) and install it.
2. Install pydev for Eclipse (instructions for that [here](http://pydev.org/manual_101_install.html))
3. Getting Python 2.7.3 for Mac OS X 10.3 ([here](http://python.org/download/releases/2.7.3/)) and install it
4. Getting Pygame 1.9.1 32-bit for Python 2.7 ([here](http://www.pygame.org/download.shtml)) and install it

Now to the proper interpreter. Go to `Eclipse->Settings->PyDev->Interpreter - Python` and there create a `New...` interpreter. The one that worked for me is found in `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin`. There just select the `python` alias which will link to the correct one then.

Now make sure that your pygame is in your PYTHONPATH. To do so just add a `New Folder` in the lower half of the current menu and navigate to your pygame path (by default it is `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages`)

Comment: You deserve thanks as well even though your answer didn't quite work out for me. But thanks for trying to help!

Comment: Nice, I was having the same problem. Thanks for posting your own solution!

Answer (score 0):

[Installing Pygame for Mac OS X 10.6.8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8275808/installing-pygame-for-mac-os-x-10-6-8)

Give that a read, it looks like you may be trying to mix and match 32/64bit libraries.  This may require you either install the correct version of python to match your dev environment or pygame to match your dev environment.

I ran into this problem before on a 64bit system that required 32bit libraries.  The fix was to force python to run in 32bit mode.

The fix to force it into 32 bit mode is include on that page

> alias python='arch -i386 /usr/bin/python[version]'

where version is of course your version.

If you are on windows i believe you can do similar as well, though I'm not sure how to alias commands in windows.

Comment: I tried this and I dont get the `no matching architecture` anymore. But he doesn't find the pygame module: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 6, in <module>
    import pygame
ImportError: No module named pygame`

Answer (score 0):

After reading your three edits, it seems like there is an architectural problem. Since PyGame doesn't work on a 64-bit platform, you need to chose the 32-bit python interpreter in this case.

Go to `Eclipse->Preferences->PyDev->Interpreters->Python Interpreter` and add a new 32-bit python interpreter. The path for 32-bit python interpreter would most probably be the same as your usual python interpreter except that the file is called "python2.7-32" instead of "python2.7" (if the python version is 2.7). So, for me it is: `"/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2.7-32"`.

Once setup, you can either make it a default interpreter or chose it from 
`Project->Properties->PyDev - Interpreter/Grammar` when using PyGame.